# Manipulating Array of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, arrayobject

I have an array of object in which I want to manipulate.

This is the array

```
const customerInformation = [
{"id":"12345678","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"1942f0e6","ownerId":"234566654","exec":{"execId":"20326379004","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"John Smith","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-1","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"234566654","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"6374595864","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"1942f0e6","ownerId":"155464348743","exec":{"execId":"1521648743","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Math Lo","accountId":"26726447342","comid":"cs169612397275616092-1","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"234566654","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"98736478","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"hblwrv890","ownerId":"98765322","exec":{"execId":"20326379004","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"James Olive","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"256644477","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"sbdbbgbg","ownerId":"32545453565","exec":{"execId":"32254655464","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Ben Right","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"99326672378372","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"sjvjvnfrrev","ownerId":"28643872329","exec":{"execId":"268474374938","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Lowe John","accountId":"2225454354","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},

]
```

What I would like to do is manipulate the array to produce a much smaller array. the array should look like this. Please note it's using a unique `comid`, that's why you only get two results. Also the second value has to return undefined, as it's the requirement

```
const obj = [{
    'id': '12345678',
    'ownerId': '234566654'
    'userConnection': '1942f0e6',
    'status' : 'Active',
    'comid' : 'cs169612397275616092-1',
    'extensionId' : '234566654',
    'phoneNumber' : '+442222222222',
    'startAt' : '2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z',
},{
    'id': undefined,
    'ownerId': '98765322'
    'userConnection': 'hblwrv890',
    'status' : 'Active',
    'comid' : 'cs169612397275616092-2',
    'extensionId' : '2763648749',
    'phoneNumber' : '+442222222222',
    'startAt' : '2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z',
}];
```

This is what my code looks like at the moment

```
var newArray= [];

customerInformation.forEach(function(element){
   newArray.push(element.exec.communication[0].comid);
})
const uniqueId = [...new Set(newArray)];

var result = uniqueId.map(function(el) {
    const [key, user] = Object.entries(customerInformation).find(([key, user]) => user.exec.communication[0].comid === el);


  var o = Object.assign({});
  o.extensionId = user.id
  o.ownerId= user.exec.communication[0].comid
  return o

})
```

This is as far as I could get. Please i just want to understand what i am doing wrong. Presume there is a better way to do this. Please it sounds lazy but am looking for a better solution

Comment: The `events` variable looks never to be defined. Can you explain in words how the array is supposed to be combined? Eg why is the first id `12345678` but the second is `undefined` (and same for the rest of the properties, other than `comid`)?

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array, this is just an array of objects with a key that has another array in it.  A multidimensional array looks like this: `var a = [
    ['foo', 1],
    ['bar', 2]
];`

Comment: Yes your right @afro its array of object. And i have corrected the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not explain how to combine the elements, so here is a wild guess below. I won't try to decode what you're doing wrong, because the code you posted does not do what you describe? *(e.g. You assign `comid` to `o.ownerId`, but your expected result does not show that, and you assign `user.id` to `o.extensionId`, but I do not see any `id` property in the original Array with the same value as an `extensionId` in the expected result)*

```js
const customerInformation = [
{"id":"12345678","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"1942f0e6","ownerId":"234566654","exec":{"execId":"20326379004","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"John Smith","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-1","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"234566654","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"6374595864","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"1942f0e6","ownerId":"155464348743","exec":{"execId":"1521648743","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Math Lo","accountId":"26726447342","comid":"cs169612397275616092-1","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"234566654","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"98736478","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"hblwrv890","ownerId":"98765322","exec":{"execId":"20326379004","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"James Olive","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"256644477","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"sbdbbgbg","ownerId":"32545453565","exec":{"execId":"32254655464","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Ben Right","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"99326672378372","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"sjvjvnfrrev","ownerId":"28643872329","exec":{"execId":"268474374938","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Lowe John","accountId":"2225454354","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}}
];

const result = customerInformation.reduce((res, el) => {
  const com = el.exec.communication[0];
  // If the result array does not contain that comid yet
  if (!res.some(el2 => el2.comid === com.comid)) {
    // Add it
    res.push({
      id: el.id,
      ownerId: el.ownerId,
      userConnection: el.userConnection,
      status: com.status,
      comid: com.comid,
      extensionId: com.extensionId,
      phoneNumber: com.phoneNumber,
      startAt: el.exec.eventTime
    });
  }
  return res;
}, []);

// Because "it's the requirement"
result[1].id = undefined;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) methods on your array.

```js
const customerInformation = [
{"id":"12345678","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"1942f0e6","ownerId":"234566654","exec":{"execId":"20326379004","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"John Smith","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-1","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"234566654","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"6374595864","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"1942f0e6","ownerId":"155464348743","exec":{"execId":"1521648743","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Math Lo","accountId":"26726447342","comid":"cs169612397275616092-1","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"234566654","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"98736478","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"hblwrv890","ownerId":"98765322","exec":{"execId":"20326379004","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"James Olive","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"256644477","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"sbdbbgbg","ownerId":"32545453565","exec":{"execId":"32254655464","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Ben Right","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"99326672378372","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"sjvjvnfrrev","ownerId":"28643872329","exec":{"execId":"268474374938","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Lowe John","accountId":"2225454354","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},

]

const obj = customerInformation.reduce(function( result, item ){
    return result.concat({
        id: item.id,
        ownerId: item.ownerId,
        userConnection: item.userConnection
        });

}, []);
console.info(obj);
```

Comment: This does not result in the output OP says is desired

Comment: The output is the same, I simply didn't use the full list of desired properties, is that what you mean?

Comment: OP's desired output is an array with 2 items. You're creating an array with an item for every item in the original array. (For that, easier to use `.map` than `.reduce`, but it's still not what OP is looking for - and the logic OP is looking for is unclear to me, other than that the result should have 2 items)

Answer (score -1):

Your example is a bit confusing, but I'll take a stab at helping.

What it sounds like you want to do is dedupe the original array, based on a key in one of the nested objects. Common way to dedupe like this is to use a map object.
and you also want to collect info from that object in a new array. You can actually do both these operations at the same time because of how object references work.

Full disclosuer: This could be written nicer with some newer JS syntax, tried to keep it simple :)

```js
const customerInformation = [
{"id":"12345678","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"1942f0e6","ownerId":"234566654","exec":{"execId":"20326379004","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"John Smith","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-1","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"234566654","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"6374595864","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"1942f0e6","ownerId":"155464348743","exec":{"execId":"1521648743","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Math Lo","accountId":"26726447342","comid":"cs169612397275616092-1","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"234566654","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"98736478","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"hblwrv890","ownerId":"98765322","exec":{"execId":"20326379004","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"James Olive","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"256644477","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"sbdbbgbg","ownerId":"32545453565","exec":{"execId":"32254655464","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Ben Right","accountId":"234566654","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
{"id":"99326672378372","timestamp":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.338Z","userConnection":"sjvjvnfrrev","ownerId":"28643872329","exec":{"execId":"268474374938","eventTime":"2019-01-21T11:53:29.223Z","communication":[{"name":"Lowe John","accountId":"2225454354","comid":"cs169612397275616092-2","status":"Active","phoneNumber":"+442222222222","extensionId":"2763648749","missedCall":false,"standAlone":false,"muted":false}]}},
]

const map = {};
const newArr = [];

for (const info of customerInformation) {
    const id = info.exec.communication[0].comid;
    if (!map[id]) {
 map[id] = {};
 newArr.push(map[id]);
    }
    Object.assign(map[id], {
 ownerId: info.ownerId,
 comid: id,
 extensionId: info.id,
 userConnection: info.userConnection
 // add whatever fields and other logic you want here
    });
}

console.log('customerInformation', newArr);
```

I didn't understand some of the question so just trying to do my best to lend a hand. Wasn't sure what you meant by `Also the second value has to return undefined, as it's the requirement`

Comment: This does not result in the output OP says is desired